# What is Backgroud Color of Cardview from?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I just want to know what cardview color background from,
its different with

```
?android:attr/windowBackground
```

See? its different, windowBackgroud color is Black, and Cardview color is Grey. Any idea?

If you don't know too, help me to up this thread hehe

[image]

Comment: You are setting window background as a colour of a text. Also in the picture there is no CardView.

Comment: where is the cardview